# MySQL - fixing consistency Problems in URL column

Tags: mysql

I have a column called **url** in my database. When creating the tuples, I made a mistake that created an inconsistency.

Half of my data is saved as 
**../api/data/image.png**, the other half is saved as **./data/image.png**

```
| id     |     url          |
|    ... | ../api/data/image
|    ... | ../api/data/image
|    ... | ./data/image
```

---

I want every url in the column to look like **/api/data/somefile_or_directory** what would be the SQL Code for that?

Comment: it would mostly look like an `UPDATE` statement, assigning a new value to the url column `SET url = expr` with an expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a simple replacement:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET url = REPLACE(url, "/data/", "/api/data/")
WHERE url NOT LIKE '%/api/%';
```

### Demo

Comment: Need to handle `.` vs `..`, so `"./data/", "../api/data/"`?

Comment: @TimLewis I interpret the `..` ellipsis as just a placeholder for the actual path which the OP isn't showing...but maybe you're right ^ ^

Comment: Ah, fair point. I'm interpreting it as a relative path, but yeah; hard to say.

Comment: I actually need it to be /api/ without any dots, your code worked just need to get rid of the dots in front of the url :)

Comment: @TimLewis I dont need . or .. that was a mistake, i want to get rid them without messing up my image.png with a REPLACE

Answer (score 0):

test expressions in a SELECT statement before incorporating them into an UPDATE statement. e.g.

```
SELECT t.url 
     , IF(t.url LIKE './data/%', CONCAT('../api/data/',SUBSTR(t.url,8)), t.url)  AS new_url
  FROM ( SELECT '../api/data/image' AS url 
         UNION ALL SELECT './data/foo' 
         UNION ALL SELECT './data'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'foo'
       ) t
```

results:

```
url                new_url 
-----------------  -----------------
../api/data/image  ../api/data/image
./data/foo         ../api/data/foo
./data             ./data
foo                foo
```

when we have an expression tested, and it gives the results we need, we can use it in an UPDATE statement

```
UPDATE mytable t 
   SET t.url = IF(t.url LIKE './data/%', CONCAT('../api/data/',SUBSTR(t.url,8)), t.url)
```